# Is it bad practice to call express routes from another?

Tags: node.js, routes, express

I have a route that could do many different things.  For example:

A route file:

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
    if (x)
        exports.login(req,res);
    else
        exports.dostuff(req,res);
};

exports.login = function(req, res) {
    res.render('login');
};

exports.dostuff = function(req, res) { 
    res.render('otherfile');
};
```

Is this bad practice?  Is there a better way of going about such a situation?  Thanks.

Comment: this question is really subjective, but sometimes it's better to just do a redirect.

Comment: ie if you're on a page that requires authentication and you render the login page instead of redirecting to the login page i will hate you

Comment: You need to take a look at using middlewares in your express app. That way, it will ensure that you are logged in (if a page requires you to login) and redirect appropriately rather than handle it in the routing yourself.

Answer (score 10):

Well this is not a bad practice but also not the most suited one for this situation.

You could do something like this to achieve better routing solution.

- Configure your routes in the router file and handle your behaviours in a specific controller.

E.g something like this. (router.js)

```js
//First requiring your controller for actions
var jobController = require("../controllers/job_controller");

module.exports = function(app) {

    app.get("/jobs", jobController.getJobIndex);
    app.get("/jobs/create", jobController.createJobView);
    app.get("/jobs/update/:id", jobController.updateJobView);
    app.get("/jobs/delete/:id", jobController.deleteJob);
    app.get("/jobs/:id", jobController.getJobDetails);

    app.post("/jobs/create", jobController.createJobPost);
    app.post("/jobs/update", jobController.updateJobPost);

};
```

And require the router.js in your main app.js

```js
var router = require('./routes/router')(app)
```